# Delphi Chromium Embedded - Create and get a cookie

Tags: delphi, cookies, chromium-embedded

I'm using Delphi Chromium Embedded in my application.
I should need to save user's account info in a cookie.
I know there's CefCookieManager to do it, but i'm not able to find the right procedure to store and to get cookie's value.

Comment: Cookies are not meant for client-side manipulation. It's simply something the server stores on your machine. However I could be wrong with your scenario.

Comment: But in Chrome my web application saves login cookie by instruction 'document.cookie'. I should need to do the same thing in Delphi Chromium Embedded.

Comment: @JerryDodge - CefCookieManager is exactly exists to client-side manipulation of cookies.

Comment: @henry60, GetCookie, SetCookie methods on CefCookieManager class. Read documentation carefully, SetCookie method can be called only on CEF IO thread. And setup cookie rightly. After you do it, loaded page will see cookies, provided by cookie manager.

Comment: Ok, but there's no GetCookie method in CefCookieManager.

Comment: How can I get cookie's value ?

Comment: Yeah, it's my bad, GetCookie is absent. You must use VisitUrlCookies or VisitAllCookies methods.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dmitry comment, after calling `VisitAllCookies`, `OnCookiesVisited` event will be triggered with all saved cookies (one by one).

It might be needed to call `VisitAllCookies` after `OnFrameAttached` is fired.

Answer (score -1):

```
Uses 
  ceflib;


const
DefaultCookiesDir = 'Cookies/';

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  CookieManager: ICefCookieManager;
  CookiesPath : String;
begin
  CookiesPath := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + DefaultCookiesDir + 'User1';
  CookieManager := TCefCookieManagerRef.GetGlobalManager;
  CookieManager.SetStoragePath(CookiesPath);
  Chromium1.Load('www.vk.com');
end;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post an answer here, please post an explanation explaining why your code works.

Comment: your code doesn't answer any part of the question. it only switches cookie storage path. You probably mean to manipulate cookies by switching entire cookie storage to a file you set up beforehand, but still... this is a very extreme and drastic semi-solution at best.